# Discord.py scheduled commands

Tags: python, discord, command, discord.py

So, I made a mute command. It works fine, but only when the bot is online, since I use asyncio.sleep for the time that was given.

How would I do it, so instead of asyncio, it would work on a schedule? Like:

Command is called:

Add a new schedule unmuting the user at the given time.
If the bot has been offline for the time, that the user was supposed to be unmuted, unmute him.

My command is this so far:

```
@commands.command()
@commands.guild_only()
@commands.has_permissions(manage_roles=True)
async def mute(self, ctx, member : discord.Member, arg: int, time, *, reason=None):

    role = discord.utils.get(member.guild.roles, name="MUTED")

    await member.add_roles(role) # ? This for some reason doesnt work


    timeSet = arg

    if time == "m":
        time = "minutes"
        arg = arg * 60
    elif time == "h":
        arg = (arg * 60) * 60
        time = "hours"
    elif time == "d":
        arg = ((arg * 60) * 60) * 24
        time = "days"
    elif time == "y":
        arg = ((((arg * 60) * 60) * 24) * 31) * 365
        time = "years"
    else:
        arg = arg

    await ctx.message.delete()

    #Setting the embed for mutes

    embedMuteServer=discord.Embed(title="MUTED", description="--------------------------------------------", color=0xff0000)
    embedMuteServer.add_field(name="Muted user", value=f"{member}", inline=True)
    embedMuteServer.add_field(name="For: ", value=f'{reason}', inline=True)
    embedMuteServer.add_field(name="For: ", value=f'{timeSet} {time}', inline=True)
    embedMuteServer.set_footer(text="-----------------------------------------------------")

    #Setting up the sending embed

    embedMute=discord.Embed(title="You were muted in", description=f"{member.guild.name}", color=0xff7800)
    embedMute.add_field(name="Reason of the mute: ", value=f"{reason}", inline=False)
    embedMute.add_field(name="The one who muted you was:", value=f"{ctx.message.author.mention}", inline=False)
    embedMute.add_field(name="You were muted for:",value=f"{timeSet} {time}")

    #Sending the embed

    try:
        await member.send(embed=embedMute)
        await ctx.send(embed=embedMuteServer)
    except: 
        pass
    print("Server and DM embeds sent")

    #Doing the command

    
    await asyncio.sleep(arg)
    await member.remove_roles(role)

    #Sending unmuted DM

    try:

        embed=discord.Embed(title="You were unmuted!", description="---", color=0x33e639)
        
        embed.add_field(name="Your muted timer has expired!", value="Try not to get muted again ", inline=False)
        await member.send(embed=embed)
        print("Unmute DM sent")

    except: 
        pass
        print("Cannot send messages to this user")
```

Answer (score 1):

You should specify the guild in a different way, there is an example below.

```py
guild = discord.utils.get(self.bot.guilds, id=ctx.guild.id)
role = discord.utils.get(guild.roles, name="MUTED")
```

and your second problem is you shouldn't make the "arg" into an int, if you do that you won't get the hour, day, week, or the month argument.

instead, you should use something like `arg.endswith("h")`

You don't need arg since you're already passing the duration in time.

Here is your fixed and slightly improved Code.

```py
@commands.command()
@commands.guild_only()
@commands.has_permissions(manage_roles=True)
async def mute(self, ctx, member : discord.Member, time, *, reason=None):

    role = discord.utils.get(member.guild.roles, name="MUTED")

    await member.add_roles(role) # ? This for some reason doesnt work

    timeSet = f"{time}"

    if time.endswith("m"):
        duration = int(time)
        arg = duration * 60
        time = "Months"
    elif time.endswith("h"):
        duration = int(time)
        arg = int(duration * 60 * 60)
        time = "Hours"
    elif time.endswith("d"):
        duration = int(time)
        arg = int(duration * 60 * 60 * 24)
        time = "Days"
    elif time.endswith("y"):
        duration = int(time)
        arg = int(duration * 60 * 60 * 24 * 31 * 365)
        time = "Years"
    else:
        arg = arg

    await ctx.message.delete()

    #Setting the embed for mutes

    embedMuteServer=discord.Embed(title="MUTED", description="--------------------------------------------", color=0xff0000)
    embedMuteServer.add_field(name="Muted user", value=f"{member}", inline=True)
    embedMuteServer.add_field(name="For: ", value=f'{reason}', inline=True)
    embedMuteServer.add_field(name="For: ", value=f'{timeSet} {time}', inline=True)
    embedMuteServer.set_footer(text="-----------------------------------------------------")

    #Setting up the sending embed

    embedMute=discord.Embed(title="You were muted in", description=f"{member.guild.name}", color=0xff7800)
    embedMute.add_field(name="Reason of the mute: ", value=f"{reason}", inline=False)
    embedMute.add_field(name="The one who muted you was:", value=f"{ctx.message.author.mention}", inline=False)
    embedMute.add_field(name="You were muted for:",value=f"{timeSet} {time}")

    #Sending the embed

    try:
        await member.send(embed=embedMute)
        await ctx.send(embed=embedMuteServer)
    except: 
        pass
    print("Server and DM embeds sent")

    #Doing the command

    
    await asyncio.sleep(arg)
    await member.remove_roles(role)

    #Sending unmuted DM

    try:

        embed=discord.Embed(title="You were unmuted!", description="---", color=0x33e639)
        
        embed.add_field(name="Your muted timer has expired!", value="Try not to get muted again ", inline=False)
        await member.send(embed=embed)
        print("Unmute DM sent")

    except discord.Forbidden: 
        pass
        print("Cannot send messages to this user")
```

Comment: Heya, thank you for the improvement of the code, however, do you know how I could achieve whats said in the title? Thank you!

Comment: You can't unmute someone while the bot is offline, because you have no way of unmuting the user when the bot is offline. If you want the bot to be able to unmute the user, you have to use APS(Advanced Python Scheduler) which helps you to do schedules even if your bot has been restarted, if the time passed after the APS time, then it will do the schedule as soon as it's online. Unfortunately, I don't know APS, Best Of Luck.